# Jersey 1.x @InjectParam inject entity

Tags: java, jersey

I have method in mine resource:

```
@Path("path/{param}")
@Post
public void method(@InjectParam MyRequest request){ ... }
```

My request class:

```
public class MyRequest{

 @PathParam("param")
 private String param;
 //Simple POJO deserialized from JSON
 private MyEntity entity;
}
```

**QUESTION:**
How do I inject **MyEntity entity** from Request to **MyRequest**? 
(@PathParam("param") injection works)

What I've tried:

1. **@Inject** and **@InjectParam** annotations, then I get new entity (not from request).
2. **@Context** annotation - nothing
3. Getting request **Request** through **@Context**, but stream for entity already closed.

**NOTE:** I need to inject entity, not just pass it as method parameter.

Comment: in what part of the request comes `MyEntity`?

Comment: MyEntity - is body of request (request content). It's a simple json request.